# Can AWS Lambda invoke guarantee different containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm currently using AWS lambda to do some short video-encoding with ffmpeg. If there is an existing container provisioned for my lambda func (with a currently running func), is it possible that if I invoke again, it will use this existing container?

This would drastically increase my function run time, since I would be doing two or more cpu heavy tasks in the container rather than just one.

If this is true, is it possible to make a lambda func start in a new container?

It kind of makes sense that lambda guarantees a certain memory allocation for each function, but if the function is cpu bound, wouldn't the container potentially bottleneck if it is being used simultaneously?

I've checked out https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/.

Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand, CPU and network scales with the memory value that you choose for your function, so I think they are not only guaranteeing memory allocation, but also CPU and network allocation. If a server with containers on it is taking too much compute power, I think they just load balance the requests and start containers on other servers. There is no way, that I know of, to guarantee that Lambda will not use a new container on each request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions execute in a container that isolates them from other functions (possibly your functions). A given container is not used by multiple Lambda invocations simultaneously.

If no existing container with your code loaded into it is free to run, then a new container is started (a 'cold start'). A given container with your code loaded into it may be reused for subsequent invocations, but only if the previous invocation has completed (a 'warm start').

You can't force Lambda to cold start any more than you can force it to warm start. It uses its own scheduling algorithm, based on its knowledge of your invocation history and its expectation of your current and future workload.

Assigned CPU is proportional to configured RAM, so simply configure RAM accordingly.

See [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) for more on container reuse in Lambda.